# Angular app - memory heap snapshot shows 3 of every service, as well as 3 AppModules, AppRouterModules and AppComponents

Tags: javascript, angular, heap-memory

In my Angular app, I am looking for memory leaks and found that when in a snapshot of the memory heap I can see 3 of every service, as well as 3 AppModules, AppRouterModules and AppComponents:

[image: Triplicated services]

[image: Triplicated AppModule]

[image: Triplicated AppComponent]

Just wondering if this is this normal, or am I triple binding somewhere? And where would I look for that.

Consider these points:

- The count does not increase as I navigate around or interact with the app.
- The count is 3 immediately after a fresh reload, if I stick a breakpoint in the ngOnInit() method - i.e. no other component has yet loaded.
- The count remains 3 even after clearing console, and requesting garbage collection.
- AppComponent is only referenced by AppModule in the `declarations`, and `bootstrap` properties once in my code.
- AppModule is only referenced in main.ts like this:

```js
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

- I'm using lazy loading
- I'm running Angular 13
- The count remains at 3 even when I run `enableProdMode()` before bootstrap